# If I click the calculate button the program crashes?

Tags: vb.net, average, calculation

Just for context;
I need to calculate the average of 5 numbers located in 5 textboxes.
Nummer means number
Gemiddelde means average
and
Bereken means calculate
What is causing it to crash?

```vb
Private Sub butBereken_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles butBereken.Click
        'Variabelen'
        Dim nummer1 As Decimal = txtNummer1.Text
        Dim nummer2 As Decimal = txtNummer2.Text
        Dim nummer3 As Decimal = txtNummer3.Text
        Dim nummer4 As Decimal = txtNummer4.Text
        Dim nummer5 As Decimal = txtNummer5.Text
        Dim somNummers As Decimal = nummer1 + nummer2 + nummer3 + nummer4 + nummer5
        Dim Gemiddelde As String = (somNummers) / 5


        lblGemiddelde.Text = Gemiddelde
        If Gemiddelde < 5.5 Then
            lblGemiddelde.Text = Gemiddelde + " Dit is onvoldoende"
        End If

        If nummer1 = "" Or nummer2 = "" Or nummer3 = "" Or
        nummer4 = "" Or nummer5 = "" Then
            butBereken.Enabled = False
            MessageBox.Show("your mom")
        Else
            butBereken.Enabled = True
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: If your program "crashes" it should provide an error (exception). It's helpful if you include the exception message in your post.

Comment: I assume you are talking about VB.Net, not VBA? Please set up your tags correclty

Comment: You should set [`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) for this project, and make it the default for new projects. It will let Visual Studio point out problems in the code for you.

Comment: If you run under the debugger, it should stop running at the point where the crash is.  You can inspect variables to understand why it is failing.  I would hypothesize that there is a problem with string-to-decimal conversion, and you should consider using `Decimal.TryParse` to avoid crashes.

Comment: Why did you declare `Gemiddelde` as a `String`?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see what would crash the program but check to that the TextBoxes have values before assigning them to numeric variables.  A Decimal value will never = "".

```
Private Sub butBereken_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles butBereken.Click 'Variabelen'

    If Not IsNumeric(txtNummer1.Text) Or _
        Not IsNumeric(txtNummer2.Text) Or _
        Not IsNumeric(txtNummer3.Text) Or _
        Not IsNumeric(txtNummer4.Text) Or _
        Not IsNumeric(txtNummer5.Text) Then
        
        MessageBox.Show ("your mom wants you to fill in all the number boxes")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim nummer1 As Decimal = CDec(txtNummer1.Text)
    Dim nummer2 As Decimal = CDec(txtNummer2.Text)
    Dim nummer3 As Decimal = CDec(txtNummer3.Text)
    Dim nummer4 As Decimal = CDec(txtNummer4.Text)
    Dim nummer5 As Decimal = CDec(txtNummer5.Text)
    Dim somNummers As Decimal = nummer1 + nummer2 + nummer3 + nummer4 + nummer5
    Dim Gemiddelde As String = (somNummers) / 5

    lblGemiddelde.Text = Gemiddelde
    If Gemiddelde < 5.5 Then
        lblGemiddelde.Text = Gemiddelde + "Dit is onvoldoende"
    End If

    If nummer1 = 0 Or nummer2 = 0 Or nummer3 = 0 Or nummer4 = 0 Or nummer5 = 0 Then
        butBereken.Enabled = False
        MessageBox.Show ("your mom")
    Else
        butBereken.Enabled = True
    End If

End Sub
```

If this doesn't work I would consider setting breakpoints in the could to determine what line is causing the crash.

If that doesn't work consider adding this line to the form's initialization:

```
butBereken.Caption = "Warning: Do not Click!"
```

Comment: This answer is [grounded in science](https://www.cnn.com/2011/10/21/tech/innovation/female-computer-voices/index.html), I guess it's maternal

Comment: @djv Lol  I had some fun with it.

Answer (score -1):

I'd do something more like:

```
Private Sub butBereken_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles butBereken.Click
    Dim TBs() As TextBox = {txtNummer1, txtNummer2, txtNummer3, txtNummer4, txtNummer5}
    Dim inputs() As String = TBs.Select(Function(x) x.Text).ToArray()
    Dim values() As Decimal
    Try
        values = Array.ConvertAll(inputs, Function(s) Decimal.Parse(s))
        Dim Gemiddelde As String = values.Average()
        lblGemiddelde.Text = Gemiddelde & If(Gemiddelde < 5.5, " Dit is onvoldoende", "")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("your mom")
    End Try
End Sub
```

I prefer this approach as it doesn't require repetitive lines of code, manually converting each TextBox to a Decimal. Since the TextBoxes are in an Array, we could also add another TextBox to the form and then add that name to the end of the Array. The rest of the code would not need to change at all; it would still just work as is.

From the Array of TextBox, we use a LINQ statement to extract the Text from each TextBox and add it to an Array of String called "inputs". From there, we  convert every single String to a Decimal using `Array.ConvertAll()`, again avoiding repetitive code. If any of the input values is not a valid Decimal then an Exception will be thrown and we'll jump the the Catch block where the not so well written error message is displayed.

If there are no exceptions, then all String inputs were successfully converted to Decimals and stored in the "values" Array. Next we simply use the LINQ function `Average()` to get the average of all the values.

Lastly we display the computed average in the Label, adding the "Dit is onvoldoende" message if approapriate. The `If()` function used in this line is simply a shorthand version of a longer `If...Else...End If` statement.

In your original attempt, it looks like you wanted to disable the button if any of the values are blank (or maybe if they are invalid decimals?):

```
If nummer1 = "" Or nummer2 = "" Or nummer3 = "" Or nummer4 = "" Or nummer5 = "" Then
    butBereken.Enabled = False
    MessageBox.Show("your mom")
Else
    butBereken.Enabled = True
End If
```

This makes no sense as if you disable the button, how would it get turned back on so that user could click it again?

A different approach would be to handle the `TextChanged()` event of all the TextBoxes and simply update your Label with the average in real-time whenever one of the TextBoxes is changed:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        UpdateAverage()
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtAll_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtNummer5.TextChanged, txtNummer4.TextChanged, txtNummer3.TextChanged, txtNummer2.TextChanged, txtNummer1.TextChanged
        UpdateAverage()
    End Sub

    Private Sub UpdateAverage()
        Dim TBs() As TextBox = {txtNummer1, txtNummer2, txtNummer3, txtNummer4, txtNummer5}
        Dim inputs() As String = TBs.Select(Function(x) x.Text).ToArray()
        Try
            Dim values() As Decimal = Array.ConvertAll(inputs, Function(s) Decimal.Parse(s))
            Dim average As Decimal = values.Average
            lblGemiddelde.Text = average & If(average < 5.5, " Dit is onvoldoende", "")
        Catch ex As Exception
            lblGemiddelde.Text = "{ Invalid Input }"
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

Sample run:

[image]

Comment: Not the downvoter but, the answer does not provide the OP with any explanation as to why one would go this route as opposed to the original. Introduces more advanced syntax and language features (not necessarily a bad thing, but again no explanations included).  Instead of introducing a `Try/Catch`, it would be better to demonstrate how to do numeric conversion safely, avoiding exceptions.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the user populated all the textboxes with numeric only data, (and you have checked this) try replacing these lines in your code with this code

```
Dim nummer1 As Decimal = txtNummer1.Text
Dim nummer2 As Decimal = txtNummer2.Text
Dim nummer3 As Decimal = txtNummer3.Text
Dim nummer4 As Decimal = txtNummer4.Text
Dim nummer5 As Decimal = txtNummer5.Text
Dim somNummers As Decimal = nummer1 + nummer2 + nummer3 + nummer4 + nummer5
Dim Gemiddelde As Decimal = somNummers / 5

lblGemiddelde.Text = Gemiddelde.ToString("##0.0")
```